# addEventListener not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

```
protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, viewOverview);
}

protected function viewOverview(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent( new ChangeSelectedIndex(1,ChangeSelectedIndex.index_passed));
}
```

I try to add the eventlistener like this, but nothing happens. I've checked, and the init function is being called from the creationcomplete statement. Below you can see the button in the containing HGroup.

```
<s:HGroup x="116" y="0" width="200" height="25">
    <s:Label id="lblOverviewTitle" fontFamily="Verdana" fontSize="24" fontWeight="bold"
             text="Artist Details"/>
    <s:Button id="btnBack" label="Back" />
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Did you trace to make sure "init" is being dispatched? Either in "creationComplete" or "initialization" or whatever you have it attached to.

Comment: Yes, init is dispatched as it should.

Comment: Remove your test click method on the component so there's no confusion. Try to 'trace' btnBack to make sure it exists.

Comment: If I trace it, it returns null.

Comment: There you go, you don't actually have a reference to btnBack. Would need to see more code, but the component doesn't exist yet. Try changing listening to "creationComplete" to "applicationComplete". Or put the code where you're listening for that in your post.

Comment: @dominic Tancredi The "proper" place to add event listeners to components in MXML is in the initialize event; as that fires right after createChildren() is called.  Most people do use creationComplete, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to add the event listneer in ActionScript?  You can do it in MXML like this:

```
<s:HGroup x="116" y="0" width="200" height="25">
    <s:Label id="lblOverviewTitle" fontFamily="Verdana" fontSize="24" fontWeight="bold"
             text="Artist Details"/>
    <s:Button id="btnBack" label="Back" click="viewOverview(event)"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

As stated in the comments to the main question, it seems like you are trying to add the event listener to btnBack before the component is created.  You should add the event listener in a [initialize](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3ainitialize) event, because initialize fires right after createChildren() is fired.

If you're building a Spark Component, and btnBack is a skin part, you should add the event listener in [partAdded()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#partAdded%28%29) method.