# addEventListener not working on any browser

Tags: javascript, onload, addeventlistener

I ran the below code and tried it on all browsers but it didn't work

```
//HTML Code
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body onload="LaunchImageSlider();">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/javascript code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//javascript code.js
function LaunchImageSlider() {
window.addEventListener("load",function() {alert("Hi")});
}
```

I did not get any alert message. My actual aim is to create an image slider once the page is loaded so I began first by seeing whether the "addEventListener" works.
What am I doing wrong here?

I referred to the below questions already, but nothing helped:

[addEventListener is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643821/addeventlistener-is-not-working)

[addEventListener() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839642/addeventlistener-not-working)

[addEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457003/addeventlistener-not-working)

[addEventListener in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189566/addeventlistener-in-javascript)

Comment: Or rather forget the `onload`

Comment: URLs cannot contain unescaped spaces.

Comment: So, you tell the browser to run some code when the page finishes loading. And that code is running some other code when the page finishes loading. But of course the page has already been loaded.

Comment: @Pointy: dO YOU mean "javascript code.js". But this works completely fine for all the pages of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/javascript code.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                LaunchImageSlider();
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But in the function you should not add and eventListener, as it is run after the window has loaded. You should just run the callback method directly. So using your example:

```
//javascript code.js
function LaunchImageSlider() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

Comment: This works. But the problem is that I want the alert to be displayed after all the images on the page have loaded. How do i do that?

Comment: There is a small library you could use: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded , unfortunately the normal document ready event does not necessarily fires after the images are loaded